# Evaluate $\iiint\limits_{\Omega}^{} \left ( x^2+y^2+z^2 \right ) dV$ and flux integral $\iint_{\partial \Omega}^{} F\cdot \overrightarrow{n} dS$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, multiple-integral

> Let F be a vector field $F = \left \langle x^3,y^3,z^3 \right \rangle $ and $\Omega$ be the solid region in $R^3$ bounded by $$x^2+y^2\ge z^2,\space x^2+y^2+z^2\le 9,\space  y\ge \left | x \right | .$$
> Evaluate $\iiint\limits_{\Omega}^{} \left ( x^2+y^2+z^2 \right ) dV$ and flux integral $\iint_{\partial \Omega}^{} F\cdot \overrightarrow{n} dS$ where $\partial \Omega$ is the boundary surface of $\Omega$.

Cause the "shape" of $\Omega$ is really hard to visualize, I failed to obtain the range of the integral. Is there any suggestion?

Comment: switch to spherical coordinates

Comment: @SineoftheTime for$\iint_{\partial \Omega}^{} F\cdot \overrightarrow{n} dS$, can I just (simply) apply divergence theorem of $F$ on $\Omega$?

Comment: yes, note that applying the divergence theorem you obtain the "first" integral multiplied by $3$

Answer (score 1):

In spherical coordinates
$$
x=r\sin\theta\cos\phi ;
y=r\sin\theta\sin\phi ;
z=r\cos\theta ;
$$
The Jacobian is $r^2\sin\theta$.
$x^2+y^2\ge z^2$ indicates $\sin^2\theta \ge \cos^2\theta$, therefore $\pi/4 \le \theta \le 3\pi/4$.
$y\ge |x|$ indicates the 2D cone $\pi/4 \le \phi \le 3\pi/4$.
$$
\int_{\Omega} (x^2+y^2+z^2) r^2\sin\theta dr d\phi d\theta
$$
$$
=\int_0^3 dr \int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4} d\phi \int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4} d\theta r^2\sin\theta r^2
$$
$$
=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^3 dr \int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4} d\theta r^2\sin\theta r^2                            
$$
$$
=\frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{2} \int_0^3 dr r^4
=\frac{243}{5} \sqrt{2} \pi
$$